# Proper function use within Python class

Tags: class, python-2.7

I am pretty new to using Python's object orientation so I have some general formatting questions.  One of which: Is there a proper way of passing data out of a function within a class?  An example being:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self,p1,p2,p3):
        self.level = p1
        self.data  = p2      

        # Is it right/wrong to call the function and make the assignment this way
        self.data = self.function1(self.data)

        # or is this method right/wrong/better?
        self.function2(self.data)

    def function1(self,data):
        self.data += 5

    def function2(self,data):
        data += 5
        return data
```

I am pretty sure that, functionally, they do the same thing within this simple example.  However, is there a good reason to go with one over the other (i.e. are there some gotchas down the road that I currently do not know about)?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to call `self.function1(self.data)` (with or without `self.data = `) from within the `__init__` method? Because otherwise this wouldn't work at all (in the class scope, `self` is not defined).

Comment: Correct.  However, when people say things like "in the class scope, self is not defined" I do not understand what that means.  How would I define self within the class?

Comment: You don't need to. `self` in the methods refers to the instance of the class, so `self.x` refers to the `x` object in the class's scope (so `class A(): x = 2`). Within the class scope you can simple call it `x` though, without the `self` because you already are in that scope.

Comment: I see.  That is a good clarification.  I thought it was getting a bit sloppy with all the self calls within the class scope.  What about passing ojbects into/out of functions within the class.  Does it matter if I I make a direct assignment (e.g. data = self.function1) or do it more passively (e.g. self.function1) as put above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ever want to use the method to modify data that isn't `self.data`, you can't use the first method. On the other hand, using the first method would make more sense if it *is* specific to the `Example` class. It will never be used to modify anything but the `self.data` variable and as such should only be able to modify that variable.

Functionally though, there is no difference. It's mostly semantics.

Comment: Sure.  I like to wait a short while before marking an answer as the preferred answer in case somebody comes back with something better/more comprehensive, etc.

Comment: I didn't even look at your profile, @tnknepp, I think I'm just assuming every question is from a new user who doesn't know how anything works because of the amount of that happening.